# Command works in CMD prompt but not when sent via SSH2 with phpseclib

Tags: php, python, terminal, phpseclib

Im using [`phpseclib`](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib) which id included with the command:

`composer require phpseclib/phpseclib ~2.0`

The target machine (receiver) is running Windows Server 2012.

On the target machine, I can run the following command in the cmd prompt and it works perfectly:

`c:/maestro/__main__.py --process-report hourly_visitor -test`

However, if I send that same command to the machine via SSH2, I get a strange error namely `__main__.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -testh`

*Note* the *h* in `-testh`. That's NOT in the sent command. Also, that extra letter seems to change, in a previous log entry, I saw: 
 `__main__.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -testt` with an extra *t* on the end but always a single letter added to the end.

I don't get it, what the heck is happening here?

Here is my php function:

```
public function triggerReport($config,$command)
{
    $host = array_get($config,'host');
    $username = array_get($config,'username');
    $password = array_get($config,'password');

    $ssh = new SSH2($host);
    if (!$ssh->login($username, $password)) {
        Log::error('Login Failed while attempting to trigger report with command: '.$command);
    }
    else{
        $output = $ssh->exec($command);
        Log::info('Output from running report with command: '.$command);
        Log::info($output);
    }
}
```

1st log output

> Output from running report with command: C:\Python27\python.exe `c:/maestro/__main__.py --process-report hourly_visitor -test`

2nd log output:

> `usage: __main__.py [-h] --process-report [REPORT_TRIGGER] [-test]
>   [--to TO [TO ...]]
>   __main__.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -testh`

Comment: Looks like you cross-posted this to github: https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/issues/1120 Anyway, I think the developers suggestion is a sound one. Please post the SSH logs from both machines. You can get them by doing `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2);` at the top of the file and then `$ssh->getLog()` after the `$ssh->exec()`.

Comment: @neubert done, if it gets resolved there Ill happily delete this question